# What does <ext: do in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

New to XSLT and cannot find an answer using Google.

I need to write a new XSLT based on an existing one, in that XSLT they use < ext: to add new tags in the resulting XML from what I understand.

Where can I find an explanation of this ?

Is this good practice ?

This is part of the XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ax="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message" xmlns:purchaserequisition="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/PurchaseRequisition" xmlns:ext="IgepaFormat" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="ext ax purchaserequisition">
        <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" version="1.0" standalone="yes" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" /> 
        <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="ext" result-prefix="#default" /> 
        <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" /> 
        <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" /> 
        <xsl:template match="ax:Envelope">
            <xsl:for-each select="ax:Body/ax:MessageParts/purchaserequisition:PurchaseRequisition">
                <ext:ORDERS>
                    <ext:Envelop>
                        <ext:RecordType>ENV</ext:RecordType>
                    <ext:OrderHeader>
                        <ext:OrderNumber>
                            <ext:BuyerOrderNumber>
                                <xsl:value-of select="purchaserequisition:VendPurchOrderJour/purchaserequisition:PurchId" />
                            </ext:BuyerOrderNumber>
                            <ext:ListOfMessageID>
                                <ext:MessageID>
                                    <ext:IDNumber>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="purchaserequisition:VendPurchOrderJour/purchaserequisition:PurchId" />
                                    </ext:IDNumber>
                                    <ext:IDAssignedBy>
                                        <IDAssignedByCoded>1</IDAssignedByCoded>
                                    </ext:IDAssignedBy>
                                </ext:MessageID>
                            </ext:ListOfMessageID>              
                        </ext:OrderNumber>
```

Comment: It's a namespace, designed to make XML overly complicated.  Not a "good" practice, but widely followed by XML newbies that read it in an XML book, and the PhDs that created the specification.

Comment: "New to XSLT and cannot find an answer using Google." Are you sure you are approaching the task of learning a new language the right way? Discovering the fundamental concepts of a language by searching on google is very unlikely to work, because until you know the concepts you don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read up on XML "namespaces"

`ext:` is a namespace prefix. If you look at the first line of your stylesheet you should see this declaration

```
xmlns:ext="IgepaFormat"
```

So, an element `<ext:ORDERS>` means the ORDERS element belongs to the namespace "IgepaFormat". Note the prefix "ext" is arbitrary in this case. It is the namespace URI that is important.

It is not really a question of good practise regarding namespaces. You use them if the XML you are outputting requires them (e.g. the application that consumes the XML you produce requires the elements to be in a particular namespace)

Here is one potential link you could read up on them at: https://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html

Comment: I think you missed one very unusual feature of this stylesheet: it uses the `xsl:namespace-alias` instruction. This means that `<ext:zzzz>` is actually not creating an element in namespace "IgepaFormat", it is creating it in namespace "#default", which in this case is no namespace. I have no idea why the stylesheet is doing this; it might be because the author thought it would be useful to be able to switch to a different output namespace by changing one line of code.